# Can I take questions from an academic textbook and publish them on my "question bank" website?

Tags: copyright, website

I have many books and worksheets for JEE (Joint Entrance Examination) in India. I want to make a website that will serve as a question bank for students. I want to take questions from these books and worksheets to use on my website.

Can I use them as such? Is paraphrasing also illegal?

Answer (score 5):

The material in all those books and worksheets you're referring to is almost certainly copyrighted.  Publishing it on your website would be copyright infringement. If you'd like to use that material, you'll need permission which you're unlikely to get.  You might try offering to pay a fee for a license, but even then, I suspect the answer will be no.  People write and publish books because they'd like sell books, not license the questions at the end of each chapter.

If you'd like to create a question bank of material for which you clearly have the necessary rights, the most straight-forward way to do this would be to write your own questions.  I would avoid paraphrasing others' questions but you could certainly think of them as examples of the topics you should try to cover in your own questions.

Comment: Note that for some books, the set of exercises is actually the most valuable part. Since they guide what the student actually does, they guide learning, perhaps more than the text itself.

Comment: Also note that the ideas in a copyrighted text aren't copyrighted, only the expression. So, you can use the concept behind an exercise to write your own. But paraphrasing and obfuscating minor changes isn't enough. Think deeper as you want the students to do.

Comment: So much for chegg's business model